# Why does the landscape table does not rotate?

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating, landscape, sidewaystable

I have made a MWE with my (long) table and very few packages.
Apparently, even if I use landscape the only thing rotating is the page but not the table in it which is what I would like to rotate instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=authoryear,uniquename=false,maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=10, hyperref=auto, uniquelist=minyear,labeldateparts=true, nohashothers=true, useprefix=true, autocite=footnote, mergedate=true ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, figurewithin=none]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cb}
\usepackage{pdflscape, array, rotating, multirow}

\begin{document}

\title{Idea Alcalà}
\author{Me^a$\footnote{Corresponding author:  me@unibocconi.it.}}
\date{%
    $^a$ Bocconi University, Italy\\
    %\today
    }

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\noindent 


\end{abstract}
\medskip 
\noindent \textbf{Keywords:} Green innovation, green firms

\noindent \textbf{JEL Codes:} 

\section{Introduction}\label{intro}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\scalebox{0.5}{
%\hspace{-6.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|lllll|lllll|lllll|lllll|lllll|}
\hline
                               & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Logit}}                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{CV-LASSO}}                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{CV-Ridge}}                                                                                                                               & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{RF}}                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{XGBoost}}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\textbf{Period}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{F1}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{AUC}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ACC.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{MCC}} & \textbf{PR-AUC} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{F1}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{AUC}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ACC.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{MCC}} & \textbf{PR-AUC} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{F1}}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{AUC}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ACC.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{MCC}} & \textbf{PR-AUC} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{AUC}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ACC.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{MCC}} & \textbf{PR-AUC} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{F1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{AUC}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ACC.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{MCC}} & \textbf{PR-AUC} \\ \hline
\textbf{1975-1985}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.68}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.65}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.70}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.40}         & 0.89            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.70}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.70}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.71}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.41}         & 0.91            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.69}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.70}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.70}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.41}         & 0.89            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.77}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.87}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.79}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.56}         & 0.92            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.74}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.73}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.73}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.47}         & 0.82            \\ \hline
\textbf{1986-1996}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.49}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.62}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.65}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.25}         & 0.80            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.50}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.70}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.65}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.27}         & 0.88            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.48}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.63}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.66}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.26}         & 0.88            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.69}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.84}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.77}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.51}         & 0.91            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.77}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.71}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.72}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.41}         & 0.83            \\ \hline
\textbf{1997-2007}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.32}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.58}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.78}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.26}         & 0.91            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.30}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.75}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.78}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.27}         & 0.92            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.26}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.74}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.78}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.24}         & 0.91            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.61}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.87}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.84}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.52}         & 0..93           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.88}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.69}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.81}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.44}         & 0.93            \\ \hline
\textbf{2008-2020}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.17}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.54}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.86}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.21}         & 0.94            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.14}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.77}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.86}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.19}         & 0.95            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.13}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.60}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.85}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.18}         & 0.94            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             &                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.90}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.66}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.88}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.43}         & 0.95            \\ \hline
\textbf{Overall sample}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.56}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.55}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.89}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.22}         & 0.41            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             &                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             &                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             &                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             &                 \\ \hline
Year Dummies                   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Yes}                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Yes}                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Yes}                                                                                                                                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Yes}                                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Yes}                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{McNeamar Test} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Logit-CV-LASSO} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}                 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-26} 
                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Logit-CV-Ridge} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Not Passed}                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CV-LASSO-CV-Ridge} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Not Passed}                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-26} 
                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Logit-RF}       & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CV-LASSO-RF}       & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CV-Ridge-RF}      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-26} 
                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Logit-XGBoost}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CV-LASSO-XGBoost}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{CV-Ridge-XGBoost} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Passed}                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{RF-XGBoost}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Not Passed}                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{.}           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{.}                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{The Table shows several precision indicators for Logit, CV-Lasso,CV-Ridge Classifier, Random Forest (500 trees) and XGBoost. The latter two have been inserted as they better deal with sparse data. In addition a CV-ElasticNet has been tested but has been not included since it did not add much more than CV-LASSO and CV-Ridge. The metrics analysed comprise F1-score, AUC, Balanced Accuracy, Matthew's coefficient and Precision-Recall AUC.  The latter performance indices are obtained as medians of the performance indices obtained extracting $N=1000$ different training and test sets. A Mcnemar's Test is added indicating no statistical difference between the (statistically) best models, i.e. Random Forest and XGBoost. }
\label{indicators_yearly}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}



\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What's going wrong here? Is there any solution?

Comment: unrelated but why have all those `\multicolum` ? `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.58}`  could be equivalently entered as `0.58`

Comment: `! Missing $ inserted.`  from `^a$`

Comment: your table does rotate [you should get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvDYQ.png)